# Submit button wrong database format

Tags: ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access 2016 and I have created a database and in a Form i have created a button
to save information in a table , the code for the submit button is :

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
  Dim qry As String
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Set db = CurrentDb

  'First date
  qry = "INSERT INTO Database2.person VALUES ('test','test',1/1/2020)"
  db.Execute qry


  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

howwever when I click it it gives me the error:
Runtime error  '3024'
Could not find file 'C:\Users\phili\Documents\Database2.mdb' , when I checked I have
C:\Users\phili\Documents\Database2.accdb' file so Microsoft Access chose a wrong format of the database , how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you actually want to insert data into a different database than the one currently open? If not, just use `INSERT INTO person VALUES ('test','test',#1/1/2020#)` (note the octothorpes to indicate a date)

Comment: Specify fieldnames to insert into. `INSERT INTO person(field1, field2, field3) VALUES('test', 'test', #1/1/2020#)`.

Comment: ah yes , this fixed it !

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is in the declaration of your db variable. MDB are old version formats, from my experience. Try changing your code to this:

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
  Dim qry As String
  Dim db As Database
  Set db = CurrentDb

  'First date
  qry = "INSERT INTO Database2.person VALUES ('test','test',1/1/2020)"
  db.Execute qry


  Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Answer does not deal with errors in SQL statement.

Comment: The error that was stated in the users post was Runtime Error 3024: Could not find file 'C:\Users\phili\Documents\Database2.mdb'. The result points to an incorrect file type not a SQL failure. That is why I posted what I did

Comment: I think you may find that the real answer is to use `INSERT INTO [Database2.accdb].person …`

Comment: Well, see response to comments under question.